# i.MX6 ULL based device sometimes can't open USB camera

Tags: camera, usb, embedded-linux, yocto, nxp-microcontroller

We are attempting to debug an issue that we are seeing with some devices where the camera module starts/stops working sometimes after a power cycle. A working camera can stop working and a non working camera can start working without any change to the device.

With the devices that no longer take photos we get messages as shown below in the kernel log:

```
[ 20.153600] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ci_hdrc
[ 20.398490] usb 1-1: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 20.403538] usb 1-1: can't read configurations, error -32
[ 20.543572] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[ 20.746370] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[ 20.883987] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ci_hdrc
[ 21.333593] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
```

some other devices will show

```
[ 20.243591] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ci_hdrc
[ 20.448903] usb 1-1: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -32
[ 20.454553] usb 1-1: chopping to 0 config(s)
[ 20.478077] usb 1-1: no configuration chosen from 0 choices
```

On the functioning devices we see this instead

```
[ 19.933590] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ci_hdrc
[ 20.294390] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device MikrOkularFullHD (053a:9230)
[ 20.308968] input: MikrOkularFullHD as /devices/soc0/soc/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input1
[ 20.320578] evbug: Connected device: input1 (MikrOkularFullHD at usb-ci_hdrc.1-1/button)
[ 20.327982] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 20.332528] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

We've tried rebooting the device, leaving it off for a few minutes then turning it back on (in case overcurrent was the issue) - but none of that has worked so far.

We are running Linux version 4.9.11-1.0.0+gc27010d

Comment: First advice in such cases *always try last vanilla* (soon, in few hours, will be v5.7-rc5). If there is no problem, bisect and find commit which fixes that. Then backport it and its dependencies.

Comment: Look also for electrical problems, such as noisy or low voltage power supplies, unshielded or ungrounded or double grounded cables, different cable routing, in a metal box or not, and so on.

Comment: Assuming that the remaining 94 devices+cameras work just fine, then your problem is most likely not software but hardware. The next step is to identify whether the problem is the camera or the linux board. Have you tried connecting the camera from a non-working system to a working board? If the camera works fine there, then the problem is likely to be the board, otherwise it is the camera. Is the board a custom one? If there is a reference development kit, try the camera and there and see if the problem goes away. You could be having a power supply or an EMC issue.

Comment: I've edited the post since the number of devices with the issue has changed. I've individually tested the non working camera (the camera module, cables, PCB and all work)

Comment: You might try asking on [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) with some photos of your cabling from the camera to the pcb, and oscilloscope traces of the power lines etc.

Comment: @ChiraghDewan does this problem happen with *all* devices or just with some?

Comment: Have seen this with many device.

Answer (score 0):

May be a power supply issue. Just use a powered usb hub to see if there are no problems.
If this resolves the issue, try to increase the capacitor in the usb power rail.